# JQuery Sortable not working when I add Scroll inside the DIV

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-ui-sortable

I am using JQuery Sortable in my application to drag div from one place to another.

Problem is When i add scroll inside the div and then I am dragging div from out of window the autoscroll from bottom it's not working. If I remove the scroll inside the div then it's working fine.

Here is the screenshot.
https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/3458649/e66274fc27934897e93466201b557dfd

I really don't know how to fix it.

Can anyone experienced this kind of issues?

Comment: Can you make a pen in codepen.io for this?

Comment: @asifsaho Here is the sample I have created https://codepen.io/krishna9720/pen/ZRVOGB/

Comment: In Second column you can see a scroll when i drag the element out of window the bottom scroll not working. But, If i remove scroll from second column it's working.

Comment: I don't get it what to drag. Can you explain a bit?

Comment: @asifsaho please check https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/3458819/6a2a7ec3373d447938fa2134ba9eba14

Comment: I am facing issue when i drag the DIV out of window. In sortable generally autoscroll works fine. But here because of second column scroll it's not working.